# E possível obter dados em tempo real em um bando de dados mysql meu banco e de asterisk

Tags: mysql, asterisk

Gostaria de saber como posso obter as informações do banco asterisk em tempo real, no meu banco só tem depois de usuário desliga o telefone ai a informação e gravada no banco, mais quero saber se e possível obter uma informação em tempo real

Comment: Esclareça seu problema específico ou acrescente outros detalhes para destacar exatamente o que precisa. Do modo como está escrito aqui, é difícil saber exatamente o que você está perguntando. Consulte a página https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para obter ajuda no esclarecimento desta pergunta.

Comment: O bilhete da chamada somente é gerado após o fim desta. Para acompanhar a duração total de uma chamada em curso você pode utilizar o CLI, por exemplo.

O comando a seguir exibe as informações dos canais estabelecidos:
# asterisk -rx 'core show channels verbose' 

O comando a seguir também exibe as informações dos canais estabelecidos, mas de forma mais concisa e melhor para trabalhar com shell script:
# asterisk -rx 'core show channels concise'